Не запускается gnome после обновления Kali
Установил Kali. Изначально не было интернета и система прекрасно запускалась, но сегодня подключил ее к интернету и обновился. После обновления не мог зайти в файловый менеджер и создавать папки на рабочем столе, решил перезапуститься. После перезапуска у меня перестала запускаться графическая оболочка gnome. Вошел в терминал (alt + f2), прописал gnome-session - ничего не произошло. Попытался ради эксперимента установить еще и xfce4. При вводе xfce4-session или xrandr - Cannot open display: . комплектующие пк и драйвера не менялись. При просмотре логов мое внимание привлекло только вот это:
В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

В ошибке написано libcamera не поддерживается

@evo, А что эта ошибка значит? Просто раньше с ней не сталкивался. И не знаете ли Вы, как ее можно исправить?
